# Source of "You can educate a fool but you can't make him think."

Tags: talmud-gemara, quotations

The internet is full of this "quote", attributing it to "The Talmud".
Is this really to be found in Mishnah or Gemara?
If so, what is the source reference?

Comment: [Googling "You can educate a fool but you can't make him think"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22You+can+educate+a+fool+but+you+can%27t+make+him+think%22) gives me some attributions to [Barry Farber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Farber), like [this one](https://www.quotelify.com/barry-farber-quotes) who quotes him a saying: "You can educate a fool, but you can’t make him think. Education is too often about stuffing the brain rather than developing the mind".

Comment: I also saw it attributed to Mark Twain.  But there seem to be a lot that claim it's from Talmud.